# Angular 2 runOutsideAngular still change the UI

Tags: javascript, angular

From my understanding of [`runOutsideAngular()`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/NgZone-class.html#!#runOutsideAngular-anchor), if I need to run something that won't trigger the Angular change detection, I need to use this function. My code is not working, however; when I click the button, the UI is changing and the number is 2.

```
@Component({selector: 'my-cmp', 
template: `<h1>{{num}}</h1>
           <button (click)="onClick()">Change number</button>`})

class MyComponent implements OnChanges {

  num = 1; 
  constructor(private _ngZone: NgZone ) {

  }

  onClick() {
    this._ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
      this.num = 2;
    }}));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If anything is causing change detection, and a bound event like `(click)="onClick()"` does cause change detection, then Angular will detect the change.

`runOutsideAngular` doesn't mean Angular won't see the change, it only means that the code run this way doesn't cause change detection, but because the click event already does, it's meaningless in your example.

Comment: So how can I run code on click without running the change detection at all?

Comment: I don't know how to invoke it from the UI without causing change detection to run. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Like with angular 1 I want to create clicks that not trigger the $digest loop

Comment: Sure, but for what purpose. I don't know Ng1 and have no experience where this might be useful. Perhaps you can wrap the button in a component, prevent bubbling of the event and call the code from there, then change detection might be local to the button component.

Answer (score 10):

**[In short]** you need to **change one line in your current code**

```
onClick() {
    this._ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
        setTimeout(()=>this.num = 2,0); // instead of this.num = 2;
    }}));
  }
```

now if you click the on the `<button>`, `this.num` will become `2`, but you won't see any change in the UI (a temporary inconsistency between view and model)

**[Explanation]** without `runOutsideAngular()`, async functions like `addEventListener()` or `setTimeout()` behaves differently ([monkey patched](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/01/zones-in-angular-2.html)). their callbacks will try to update UI with Angular after running user's code.
For example, you can treat `(click)="onClick()"` as:

```
addEventListener("click",function modifiedCallback(){
    onClick();
    updateUIifModelChanges(); //call to Angular
})
```

In order to not triggered UI update we need to satisfy the following two conditions:

1. **not** modify model in function `onClick` (so, modify inside `setTimeout()`)
2. when the model is indeed modified, do **not** invoke `updateUIifModelChanges` (call `setTimeout()` inside `runOutsideAngular`)

**[More]** of cause, the explanation I gave is a very very...simplified version of what happens. `setTimeout()` has the same function signature whether it's running inside `runOutsideAngular()` or not. The reason that it behaves differently is because it's running in a different [Zone](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/01/22/understanding-zones.html)

Answer (score 7):

If you want to prevent change detection then you can

**1)** subscribe on `ngZone.onMicrotaskEmpty` like this:

```
import { NgZone, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/first';

...
export class MyComponent {
  constructor(private ngZone: NgZone, private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  onClick() {
    // to do something

    this.cdRef.detach();
    this.ngZone.onMicrotaskEmpty.first().subscribe(() => {
      // reattach changeDetector after application.tick()
      this.cdRef.reattach();
    });
  }
}
```

This handler will run after `Application.tick`

See also **[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/6Ea2PFW9a186TBQxES1r?p=preview)**

**2)** use custom directive like this:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[outSideEventHandler]'
})
class OutSideEventHandlerDirective {
  private handler: Function;

  @Input() event: string = 'click'; // pass desired event
  @Output('outSideEventHandler') emitter = new EventEmitter();

  constructor(private ngZone: NgZone, private elRef: ElementRef) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
      this.handler = $event => this.emitter.emit($event);
      this.elRef.nativeElement.addEventListener(this.event, this.handler);
    });
  }

  ngOnDestory() {
    this.elRef.nativeElement.removeEventListener(this.event, this.handler);
  }
}
```

and then in template you can write:

```
<button (outSideEventHandler)="onClick()">Click outside zone</button>
```

or

```
<button event="mousedown" (outSideEventHandler)="onClick()">Click outside zone</button>
```

**[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/01L2iqifx48EvkRBAEoI?p=preview)**

**3)** write custom DOM event handler as described in this article.

- https://medium.com/@TheLarkInn/creating-custom-dom-events-in-angular2-f326d348dc8b#.bx4uggfdy

**Other solutions see here:**

- [Angular 2 how to keep event from triggering digest loop/detection cycle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43108155/angular-2-how-to-keep-event-from-triggering-digest-loop-detection-cycle/43294113#43294113)

Answer (score 5):

Using `ngZone.run` is a bit better than the `setTimeout` solutions since it uses angular specific functionality. Run is meant to be used within `ngZone.runOutsideAngular` functions.

From the docs:

> Running functions via run allows you to reenter Angular zone from a
>   task that was executed outside of the Angular zone (typically started
>   via {@link #runOutsideAngular}).

This is actually a very practical example of say a button that increments a number by one but only triggers change detection when the number is even.

```html
    @Component({selector: 'my-cmp', 
    template: `<h1>{{num}}</h1>
               <button (click)="onClick()">Change number</button>`})

    class MyComponent implements OnChanges {

      num = 1; 
      constructor(private _ngZone: NgZone ) {

      }

      onClick() {
        this._ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
          if(this.num % 2 === 0){
              // modifying the state here wont trigger change.
              this.num++;
          } else{
            this._ngZone.run(() => {
                this.num++;
            })
          }
        
        }}));
      }
    }
```

Comment: I don't think this works, because `runOutsideAngular` is *synchronous*.  The callback is invoked immediately, i.e. before `onClick` returns.  Change detection is always triggered after the `(click)` event, so your code is no different in practice from the code in the OP.  That's why the (working) examples call `setTimeout` inside `runOutsideAngular`, because any changes made before `onClick` returns will be detected regardless of what Zone they were made in.

Answer (score 1):

```
...
constructor(
        private ngZone: NgZone
){
    ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
        setInterval(()=>{
            this.num= new Date().Format('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
        },1000);
    });
}
...
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I have tried to check the difference insideAngular and OutsideAngular

```
constructor(private zone: NgZone) { }
    
        setProgressOutsideAngular() {
            this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
                setInterval(() => { ++this.progress, console.log(this.progress) }, 500)
            })
        }
    
        setProgressInsideAngular() {
            this.zone.run(() => setInterval(() => { ++this.progress, console.log(this.progress) }, 500))            
    
        }
```