# Angular 2 ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush trigger ngAfterViewChecked when Inputs does not change

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using the OnPush strategy and according to this [article](https://vsavkin.com/immutability-vs-encapsulation-90549ab74487#.ogkvb450u) if no inputs change, there is no need to check the component’s template.
But in my example when I am clicking the trigger button and the inputs does not change in this case the **ngAfterViewChecked** hook still running. What am I missing?

```
import {Component, NgModule, Input, ChangeDetectionStrategy} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'

@Component({
  selector: 'cmp',
  template: `
    <h1>{{data.name}}</h1>
  `,
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class Cmp {
  @Input() data;

  ngOnChanges() {
    console.log('ngOnChanges');
  }

  ngAfterViewChecked() {
    console.log('view checked');
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <cmp [data]="data"></cmp>
      <button (click)="trigger()">trigger</button>
      <button (click)="change()">Change</button>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  constructor() {
    this.data = {
      name: 'Angular'
    }
  }

  trigger() {

  }

  change() {
    this.data = {
      name: 'Angular2'
    };
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App, Cmp ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40300635/angular-2-runoutsideangular-still-change-the-ui/40301972#40301972

Answer (score 2):

You're not missing anything. Your expectations about `ngAfterViewChecked` are right and it's not called for subtree components when the parent `changeDetectionStrategy` is `OnPush`.

There is currently an [issue opened on Github](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7055) and it seems that triggering the lifecycle callback is not the only problem because some checks are actually made.

Comment: It's called on the Cmp and it shouldn't.

Comment: Yes it shouldn't for `Cmp`. This is actually a reported bug, but I clarified that it doesn't happen for subtree components.