# this._ngZone.onMicrotaskEmpty.first() - explanation of code

Tags: angular

Someone helped me with a async problem almost 2 months ago, it it works really nice (and I have since added allot to it), but I still have this code in my program that I am not completely sure what it does.

The original code was:

```
constructor(private ngZone: NgZone) { }

ngOnInit() { 
   this.getPosts()
     .subscribe(x => { 
        this.apidata = x;
        this.ngZone.onMicrotaskEmpty.first().subscribe(() => {
          this.largestHeight(); 
        });
      });
}
```

Now it is so hard getting documentation on this, and I have tried on and off for the last 2 months now. They just give a deffinition, but not real examples. The actual line would be `this.ngZone.onMicrotaskEmpty.first().subscribe(()`

1) So **ngZone** basically access the zone that you are busy with and I understand this 70%

2) **onMicrotaskEmpty** *"Notifies when there is no more microtasks enqueue in the current VM Turn"*.

- a) first, does VM stand for "Virtual Machine"? It was difficult just
  to get the definition of this.
- b) Does it notify when the microtask    queue of the whole app is
  empty, or just the component? If it is the    whole app, and I put
  this code in another component as well, which one will run first when the queue is empty?
- c) It says it hints to Angular to run change detection. So what does
  "hint" mean? When will Angular run change detection and when won't
  it?
- d) If I change onMicrotaskEmpty with onStable, the code still runs
  fine. Are they basically the same thing? (They both run when all the microtasks are finished)

3) **first()** The only explanation of this method I got was from w3school: *"The first() method returns the first element of the selected elements."* So what I don't understand is in the code above, what elements did I select. I tried to run a console.dir and .log on this but all I get is `[object Object]`. So I would like to know the *first* of what elements?

4) **subscribe()** I do not really know why there is a subscribe here. I was under the impression that you can only subscribe to observable's/promises. Can you subscribe to anything that can give a change through, and then run the subscribe block of code when it changes? If so, what in the previous methods are the method that changes that triggered the subscribe to run?

I hope it seems that I have tried and searched for answers for the above, but everything seems to be written for people who would not need to read it in the first place ... :P

Comment: **check this link, you will get a idea about ngzone**
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40300635/angular-2-runoutsideangular-still-change-the-ui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40300635/angular-2-runoutsideangular-still-change-the-ui)

Answer (score 2):

Vm is not a virtual-machine, i do not know what it is either but Zone in Angular is an execution context to help you manage multiple async operations.
More about it here.

[Understanding Zone](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/01/zones-in-angular-2.html)

`this.ngZone.onMicrotaskEmpty` is an Observable stream and `first()` is an operator which returns the first value emitted by that stream since an observable stream can have many different values over time

`subscribe()` is the only way to get values from that stream or be notified when there are some values being pushed to that stream

I suggest you do some reading about zone and Rxjs observables, it will clear much of your confusions

Answer (score 0):

What you need to understand about `onMicrotaskEmpty` is that it waits for the **microtask** queue to be empty, not the **macrotask**

The microtask has tasks that are directly part of the code you are executing. So say in your code you make an HTTP call and wait for it to resolve via a promise - *that* is in the microtask.

The macrotask queue has tasks that are more global. For example a mouse move, or something in a `setTimeout`.

So when you wait for microtask to be empty, it means you want to run right after the current "process" is complete but before the engine handles the next task in the macrotask.

[Also see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25933985/10139616) for some further discussion

Hope that helps