# Angular 2 how to keep event from triggering digest loop/detection cycle?

Tags: angular, event-handling, mouseevent

We are implementing drag and drop functionality with Angular 2.

I'm using the `dragover` event just to run the `preventDefault()` function. So that the `drop` event works as explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21341021/3156644).

The `dragover` method is being handled by the `onDragOver` function in the component.

```
<div draggable="true"
    (dragover)="onDragOver($event)">
...
```

In the component, this function prevents default behavior allowing for the dragged item to be dropped at this target.

```
onDragOver(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

This works as expected. The dragover event gets fired every few hundred milliseconds.

But, every time the `onDragOver` function is called, Angular 2 runs its digest cycle. This slows down the application. I'd like to run this function without triggering the digest cycle.

A workaround we use for this is subscribing to element event and running it outside of the Angular 2's context as follows:

```
constructor( ele: ElementRef, private ngZone: NgZone ) {
    this.ngZone.runOutsideAngular( () => {
        Observable.fromEvent(ele.nativeElement, "dragover")
            .subscribe( (event: Event) => {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        );
    });
}
```

This works fine. But is there a way to achieve this without having to access the nativeElement directly?

Comment: What do you mean by "digest cycle keeps getting triggered every time that something is dragged over the target" ? You mean like every element which is already inside the div triggers this event?

Comment: @echonax I've updated the quesiton:  

The dragover event gets fired every few hundred milliseconds as we expect it to. 

But, every time the `onDragOver` function is called with this, Angular 2 runs its digest cycle. This slows down the application. 

I'd like to run this function without triggering the digest cycle.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**1)** One interesting solution might be overriding `EventManager`

**custom-event-manager.ts**

```typescript
import { Injectable, Inject, NgZone  } from '@angular/core';
import { EVENT_MANAGER_PLUGINS, EventManager } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Injectable()
export class CustomEventManager extends EventManager {
  constructor(@Inject(EVENT_MANAGER_PLUGINS) plugins: any[], private zone: NgZone) {
    super(plugins, zone); 
  }

  addEventListener(element: HTMLElement, eventName: string, handler: Function): Function {
    if(eventName.endsWith('out-zone')) {
      eventName = eventName.split('.')[0];
      return this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => 
          super.addEventListener(element, eventName, handler));
    } 

    return super.addEventListener(element, eventName, handler);
  }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```typescript
  ...
  providers: [
    { provide: EventManager, useClass: CustomEventManager }
  ]
})
export class AppModule {
```

Usage:

```typescript
<h1 (click.out-zone)="test()">Click outside ng zone</h1>

<div (dragover.out-zone)="onDragOver($event)">
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/eEYnPBsoWiDELxwmaXGw?p=preview)**

So with solution above you can use one of these options to prevent default behavior and run event outside angular zone:

```
(dragover.out-zone)="$event.preventDefault()"
(dragover.out-zone)="false"
(dragover.out-zone)="!!0"
```

**2)** One more solution provided by Rob Wormald is [using blacklist for Zonejs](https://gist.github.com/robwormald/cb12881da7cbc73cf65dd042fad7b0fb)

**blacklist.ts**

```typescript
/// <reference types='zone.js/dist/zone.js' />

const BLACKLISTED_ZONE_EVENTS: string[] = [
  'addEventListener:mouseenter',
  'addEventListener:mouseleave',
  'addEventListener:mousemove',
  'addEventListener:mouseout',
  'addEventListener:mouseover',
  'addEventListener:mousewheel',
  'addEventListener:scroll',
  'requestAnimationFrame',
];

export const blacklistZone = Zone.current.fork({
  name: 'blacklist',
  onScheduleTask: (delegate: ZoneDelegate, current: Zone, target: Zone,
                   task: Task): Task => {

    // Blacklist scroll, mouse, and request animation frame events.
    if (task.type === 'eventTask' &&
        BLACKLISTED_ZONE_EVENTS.some(
            (name) => task.source.indexOf(name) > -1)) {
      task.cancelScheduleRequest();

      // Schedule task in root zone, note Zone.root != target,
      // "target" Zone is Angular. Scheduling a task within Zone.root will
      // prevent the infinite digest cycle from appearing.
      return Zone.root.scheduleTask(task);
    } else {
      return delegate.scheduleTask(target, task);
    }
  }
});
```

**main.ts**

```typescript
import {blacklistZone} from './blacklist'

blacklistZone.run(() => {
  platformBrowser().bootstrapModuleFactory(...)
})
```

**[Plunker with blacklist](https://plnkr.co/edit/f1HolscCcJkMLpuEuQVk?p=preview)**

**Update:**

**5.0.0-beta.7 (2017-09-13)**

[fix(platform-browser): run BLACK_LISTED_EVENTS outside of ngZone](https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/d52f426)

Follow

- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/19989
- https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/e82812b9a9992bc275bba54575f9d780753c1f8f
- https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/21681

**Update 2**

Angular cli includes template for disabling parts of macroTask/DomEvents patch.

Just open

**polyfills.ts**

You can find there the following code

```
/**
 * By default, zone.js will patch all possible macroTask and DomEvents
 * user can disable parts of macroTask/DomEvents patch by setting following flags
 */

 // (window as any).__Zone_disable_requestAnimationFrame = true; // disable patch requestAnimationFrame
 // (window as any).__Zone_disable_on_property = true; // disable patch onProperty such as onclick
 // (window as any).__zone_symbol__BLACK_LISTED_EVENTS = ['scroll', 'mousemove']; // disable patch specified eventNames
 /*
 * in IE/Edge developer tools, the addEventListener will also be wrapped by zone.js
 * with the following flag, it will bypass `zone.js` patch for IE/Edge
 */
// (window as any).__Zone_enable_cross_context_check = true;
```

[https://github.com/angular/devkit/blob/8651a94380eccef0e77b509ee9d2fff4030fbfc2/packages/schematics/angular/application/files/**sourcedir**/polyfills.ts#L55-L68](https://github.com/angular/devkit/blob/8651a94380eccef0e77b509ee9d2fff4030fbfc2/packages/schematics/angular/application/files/__sourcedir__/polyfills.ts#L55-L68)

See also:

- https://angular.io/guide/browser-support#polyfills-for-non-cli-users

Comment: #2 Really helped me out.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: Could you provide a plunker for example 2? Something I'm looking for however its unclear where 'Zone' is imported from or referenced ?

Comment: @Ashg I updated answer. You can also include zone types in tsconfig instead of Triple-Slash Directive like https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/core/tsconfig-build.json#L16. Or if you don't want to have types then just use `declare let Zone: any` and `any` for such types like `ZoneDelegate`, `Task` etc

Comment: Thanks yurzui for that, I figured that part out eventually, however when I did implement this solution, I still found that expressions were being evaluated on mouse movements, the onScheduleTask was being invoked after the component expression was evaluated which to me defeats the purpose, unless I am missing something. Hence why I thought a working Plunker would be helpful.  Thank you anyway.

Comment: @Ashg Added plunker. As you can angular won't run change detection on mousemove. Only when you click on Update button

Comment: `__zone_symbol__BLACK_LISTED_EVENTS` didn't work for me at all, but the CustomEventManager is perfect! :) My drag'n'drop came from inusable to perfect after `(dragover.out-zone)="..."`.

Answer (score 9):

You can detach the change detector to prevent change detection to be invoked for a component

```
constructor(private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef) {}
foo() {
  this.cdRef.detach();
  ...
  this.cdRef.attach();
}
```

Comment: While this works to detach the change detection inside the function(for a specific set of lines), when the event is first fired and the function is executed, the digest loop still runs. Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: Perhaps detach it in the constructor. I don't think there is a generic rule that works for all cases.

Comment: What if the function has a return statement?

Comment: That's expected, otherwise binding to a function wouldn't make sense anyway.