# Exclude websocket from zonejs

Tags: angular, websocket, zonejs

I am rewriting app based on angular 1 to angular 2. In my app there is websockets. Each time when app gets message from websocket it runs `zone.runTask` (because `websocket.onmessage` is async function) and in the end it update `$digest` circle from angular1. This is normal behaviour. But app gets ~3000 websocket messages per second and `zonejs` runs with `$digest` circle 3000 times per second and it spoils performance up to freeze.

I want to exclude `websocket.onmessage` from `zonejs` control, wait untill all messages will be downloaded and then run `zonejs` using `setTimeout` function.

So my questions are:
Is there a way to exclude `websocket.onmessage` from `zonejs` control?
Or how to get back standart `websocket.onmessage` behaviour without monkey patching by `zonejs`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43108155/angular-2-how-to-keep-event-from-triggering-digest-loop

Answer (score 2):

you may try `runOutsideAngular` for your websocket calls.

Read more about it [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/NgZone-class.html#!#runOutsideAngular-anchor).

Hope this helps!!