# Angular: Disable Change Detector for an entire class (service or component)

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-services

Is there a way to completely disable Angular's change detector if events that normally cause the change detection to run (setTimeout, setInterval, browser events, ajax calls etc..), are coming from a specific class (service or component)?

Namely, it seemed totally wrong to me when I found out that the `setInterval` registered in my service causes the global change detection to run every second..

I'm aware I can wrap my code inside the `NgZone.runOutsideAngular` method's callback, but I'd prefer the solution where the change detector can be disabled for an entire class, as I have other chunks of code within the service that are needlessly running the detection too.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you checked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43108155/angular-2-how-to-keep-event-from-triggering-digest-loop ?

Comment: 'Error: No provider for ChangeDetectorRef!'. Seems that provider for ChangeDetectorRef is not available for a service.

Comment: Why would you want to run change detection in a service? It does not have view.

Comment: I'm not trying to run change detection in a service, I'm trying to prevent the service from running the change detection.

Comment: Can you give an example on how a service method triggers change detection?

Comment: Just register the setInterval or setTimeout in any service, it automatically triggers the change detection for entire app.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One possible solution might be the following `@RunOutsideAngular` decorator for your service:

```
declare let Zone: any;

export function RunOutsideAngular(target: any) {
  Object.getOwnPropertyNames(target.prototype)
    .filter(p => typeof target.prototype[p] === 'function')
    .forEach(p => {
      let originalMethod = target.prototype[p];  
      target.prototype[p] = function (...args) {
        let self = this;
        Zone.root.run(() => originalMethod.apply(self, args));
      }
    });

  let ctor: any = function (...args) {
    let self = this;
    return Zone.root.run(() => target.apply(self, args));
  };
  ctor.prototype = target.prototype;
  return ctor;
}
```

**[Plunker Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/HVwJgEEIyozDMeIPMIcD?p=preview)**

If you want to disable only `setTimeout` and `setInterval` within some class you can patch these functions

```
function patchTimers(timers: any[]) {
    timers.forEach((timer) => {
        let originalMethod = window[timer];
        window[timer] = function (...args) {
            let self = this;
            if (Zone.current['__runOutsideAngular__'] === true && Zone.current.name === 'angular') {
                Zone.root.run(() => originalMethod.apply(self, args));
            } else {
                originalMethod.apply(this, arguments);
            }
        };
    })
}
patchTimers(['setTimeout', 'setInterval']);
```

and create decorator like this

```
export function RunOutsideAngular(target: any) {
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(target.prototype)
        .filter(p => typeof target.prototype[p] === 'function')
        .forEach(p => {
            let originalMethod = target.prototype[p];
            target.prototype[p] = function (...args) {
                Zone.current['__runOutsideAngular__'] = true;
                originalMethod.apply(this, args);
                delete Zone.current['__runOutsideAngular__'];
            }
        });

    let ctor: any = function (...args) {
        Zone.current['__runOutsideAngular__'] = true;
        let instance = target.apply(this, args);
        delete Zone.current['__runOutsideAngular__'];
        return instance;
    };
    ctor.prototype = target.prototype;
    return ctor;
}
```

Then you can use it as follows

```
@RunOutsideAngular
export class Service {
  constructor() {
    setInterval(() => {
      console.log('ctor tick');
    }, 1000);
  }

  run() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('tick');
    }, 1000);

    setInterval(() => {
      console.log('tick interval');
    }, 1000)
  }
}
```

**[Plunker Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/VOMdqcLF7nrYBXWcbWtm?p=preview)**

Comment: This came in really handy when calling external legacy JS code from an angular project - `Zone.root.run(() => legacyCodeThatShouldReallyBePorted(foo, bar));`. no more change detection spam by `setInterval()` somewhere deep in a mess of old code. perfect!

Answer (score 5):

You can change the detection strategy of individual components with the following:

```
import { Component, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'ws-layout-page',
  templateUrl: './layout-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./layout-page.component.css'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class LayoutPageComponent {

}
```

I dont know any other method that could archieve some selective turn on/of depending of where is the information coming from

Comment: It will only stop checking view for current component

Comment: Would be better to be in control of which aspect to exclude. Totally removing framework component can have other complicated effects as well. Goal should be to reuse or customize framework components as much as possible

Answer (score 1):

Change Detection starts at the very top of your component tree and is triggered by zone.js.
An async operation like setTimeout is picked up by zone.js which notifies angular that changes might have happened. Angular then runs change detection top-down on the component tree.
Detaching a single class from the change detector will cut out that class (i.e. directive) from change detection but won't stop change detection from being run on the rest of your component tree.
For your needs `ngZone.runOutsideAngular(...)` is the way to go, because it stops zone.js from notifying angular about your async operation thus entirely preventing change detection from being run.