# @ViewChild property is causing strange change detection issues

Tags: angular, monaco-editor

I am using the latest Angular along with the latest [MonacoEditor](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/) in order to create an application that allows you to edit code directly in the browser.  I had it all working great until today when I realized that the @ViewChild element that I am using to grab the DOM element and bind to the MonacoEditor was triggering hundreds of change detection cycles every second when hover/clicking/etc inside of the editor.

I am using this line to get a handle on the DOM element:

`@ViewChild('editor') editor;`

My view looks like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div #editor style="min-height:600px"></div>
</div>
```

And lastly to bootstrap it in my application:

```
this._editor = monaco.editor.create(this.editor.nativeElement, {
    language: 'powershell'
});
```

As soon as the last code below is ran and the monaco editor is attached to the application, all of a sudden the number of digest cycles increases a ton. Simple mousemove events in the editor causes a change detection and I quickly see thousands of detections occur in just a few seconds.  As soon as I remove the bottom lines of code the issues all go away.

The primary reason I am forced to fix this is somehow the editor here is messing with another component altogether and causing the change detection to do some weird things that in-turn causes views to re-render over a again and again. This re-rendering causes my `*ngFor` loops to fail if I ever use a function to get the iterable object.

I have been poking at this issue for hours before I finally realized it was caused by the Monaco Editor. I have played around with the `ChangeDetectionRef` class, but detaching the change detection doesn't seem to have any affect on the editor.

I'm fairly new to the latest versions of Angular (recently came from 1.x) so maybe I just need a special way of bootstrapping this editor so it doesn't do this.  I want to be able to control the detection manually but I haven't seen that work at all so far using `ChangeDetectionRef`

**UPDATE**

Forgot to mention that I did try using `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` as well to help control the change detection and it seems to have no effect at all on the underlying detection that is occurring.

Comment: did you try setting `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` in your component declaration?

Comment: Oh yes, sorry forgot to mention that I tried this and it seemed to have no effect on the digests

Comment: You could try the solution in this answer, using a `@RunOutsideAngular` decorator to completely disable all change detection. It sounds like the monaco editor is emitting tons of events which will keep firing change detection even when you're using onPush. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44406700/angular-disable-change-detector-for-an-entire-class-service-or-component

Comment: Hmm so I tried that out real quick and it seems to have other side-effects like no longer providing DI for the class so my ActivatedRoute and other injected objects are all `undefined` now.  I think this does a little too much. If anything it would be nice to be able to control the change detection at a per-property level

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be somewhat of a radical change, but you might try https://github.com/atularen/ngx-monaco-editor which is an Angular wrapper for the Monaco Editor, rather than trying to integrate it yourself.

Comment: This actually did end up fixing the issue at hand after some playing around with my angular.json file to get it to work with 7.x. Thanks a lot!