# Angular 4, trying to understand change detection

Tags: angular, angular2-changedetection

I'm trying to understand how change detection and ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush actually work, here is an example of something weird I cannot understand:

[plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/sEFqygRkh45eVRwnQhmG?p=preview)

I create a father component with the following template:

```
<app-matrix-reader *ngFor="let m of fooService.getMatrices()" [matrix]="m"></app-matrix-reader>
```

The child component app-matrix-reader has an input text.

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="matrix.a" /><br/>
```

If I simply click through the inputs multiple times (even without change its value) the function getMatrices is called.

Why the function getMatrices() is called? I also put changeDetectionStrategy.OnPush so the components should be checked and updated only if their input are updated...

Thank you

Comment: Angular is just checking if something has changed after going in and out an input, and to check that it needs to take the original values an compare with the current ones

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this answer

- [Change Detection issue -- Why is this changing when it's the same object reference with On Push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42312075/change-detection-issue-why-is-this-changing-when-its-the-same-object-referen/42312239#42312239)

Angular will run change detection cycle whenЖ

...

2) **a bound event (like `(click)` or some host listener) is triggered from the component (that is your case)**

> If I simply click through the inputs multiple times (even without
>   change its value) the function getMatrices is called.

You're firing [`blur` event on `input`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/directives/default_value_accessor.ts#L53) so angular will mark tree to your component to be checked and execute change detection

Comment: is there a way to avoid it?

Comment: I don't understand why it happens even with ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush, it should set the ChecksEnabled = false, right?

Comment: @user2010955 Angular resets ChecksEnable when handle event https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/core/src/view/util.ts#L135

Comment: I see, pfff, my applications creates a lot of children components in a complex multi levels tree and it becomes slow over time, I must understand how change detection really works and skip some useless default change detection cycles

Comment: Look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43108155/angular-2-how-to-keep-event-from-triggering-digest-loop/43294113#43294113

Comment: Thank you i'm reading it, I've added a console log in ngDoCheck in my components, and simply scrolling the page or focusing an input text I got 6000 log rows and it reeeeeally slow

Comment: 8000 (or more?) ngDoCheck takes 10 seconds... hmmm